# How to add horizontal scroll to QLabel?

Tags: python, pyqt6

I am making a calculator in PyQT and I have a QLabel with text overflow as shown below. I tried using `overflow: scroll` with QSS but as expected it is not supported.

[image: Text overflow !]

Is there a way I can scroll horizontally in a QLabel or do I have to use another widget ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I dont think user will be happy if you force him to scroll label to read it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added a bit more context in my question. I am making a calculator and sometimes the result or the expression gets too big. I though about re-sizing characters and fixing a limit... But wouldn't a scroll bar be nicer ?

Comment: QSS are *based* on CSS2.1, if a property is not supported by that CSS specification or is not listed in the [reference documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-properties), it means that it doesn't work in Qt. Use a QTextEdit in read only mode, and set the wrapMode to `WrapAnywhere`.